# Wix: LogonUser Property is not returning the expected value

Tags: wix

I am using WiX 3.9. Is there a way to get the current logged on user name in Wix. I have been reading lots of online helps and articles but so far nothing helped...maybe I am making some silly mistake.
I have added the following code:

```
  <PropertyRef Id="LogonUser" />

  <Control Type="Edit" Id="UserNameEdit" Width="139" Height="15" X="191" Y="128" Property="USER_NAME" Text="[LogonUser]" />
```

But this gave me the following error: **error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol Property:LogonUser** I have no clue how to fix that.

So I just removed the PropertyRef code but then [LogonUser] is being printed as it is **[LogonUser]** in the edit box and it does not print the actual user name.

Also when I examine the Install log file I can very well the LogonUser Property as follows:

```
 Property(C): LogonUser = JS.K
```

I have used the PropertyRef for WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS etc. and it worked fine but for LogonUser it does not. Am I missing any dll to reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```html
 <Control Type="Edit" Id="UserNameEdit" Width="139" Height="15" X="191" Y="128" Property="USER_NAME" >
<Text>{\DlgTitleFont}USER_NAME</Text>
  <Publish Property="USER_NAME" Value="[LogonUser]" Order="1">1</Publish> 

  </Control>
```

because you need to explicitly set the property for an edit control.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LogonUser` afaik. You should create a new property, and initialize it like so:

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALL_USERNAME" Value="[%USERDOMAIN]\[%USERNAME]" />
```

Schedule that before your UI is being shown:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <SetProperty Id="INSTALL_USERNAME" Before="Show" Value="[%USERDOMAIN]\[%USERNAME]" /> 
</InstallUISequence>
```